# Generating all complete pair-wise listing of a starting list

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

It might well turn out that this question has already been asked; my problem is that I don't know how to describe it succinctly enough to search.

I have a list of 12 elements. If I take 2 elements from the list at a time, how many complete (i.e., 6-pair) pair-wise partitionings of the list are there. I think that this is:

`Binomial[12,2]*Binomial[10,2]*Binomial[8,2]*Binomial[6,2]*Binomial[4,2]*Binomial[2,2]`

which gives `7,484,400` but since I don't care about how each choice of 6 pairs is ordered, I can reduce that number to `7,484,400 / 6!` giving `10,395`.

I'd like to generate those 10,395 6-pair sets. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than filtering 7M+ partitions, we can directly generate the desired partitions using [`ReplaceList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html) and [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html):

```
ClearAll[rule, twoPartitions]

rule = {a_List, x_, b___, y_, c___} :> {Join[a, {{x, y}}], b, c};

twoPartitions[list_List /; EvenQ[Length @ list]] := Map[Splice]@
  Nest[Catenate @* Map[ReplaceList[rule]], {Prepend[{}] @ list}, Length[list]/2]

twoPartitions[n_Integer?EvenQ] := twoPartitions[Range[n]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Length @ twoPartitions[12]
```

> ```
> 10395
> ```

```
Short[twoPartitions[12] , 5]
```

[image]

***Timing comparisons:***

```
First @ RepeatedTiming[res1 = twoPartitions[12]]
```

> ```
> 0.0453613
> ```

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
First @ RepeatedTiming[res2 = Cases[KSetPartitions[12, 6], p : {{_, _} ..} :> p]]
```

> ```
> 3.35389
> ```

```
kSP = ResourceFunction["KSetPartitions"];
First @ RepeatedTiming[res3 = Cases[kSP[12, 6], p : {{_, _} ..} :> p]]
```

> ```
> 3.44554
> ```

```
Equal @@ (Sort /@ {res1, res2, res3})
```

> ```
> True
> ```

***Further examples:***

```
Row[Column @* twoPartitions /@ Range[2, 6, 2], Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
twoPartitions[CharacterRange["A", "F"]] // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
t = Cases[KSetPartitions[Range[12], 6], p : {{_, _} ..} :> p]
Length@t
```

> 10395

Comment: Thank you. I can see how the `KSetPartitions` function is working. I'd be very grateful if you could briefly explain the parts of the pattern used in the `Cases` function, and the use of the `:>` operator there.

Comment: `{{_, _} ..}` is a repeating list pattern of two element sublists. `:>` may not be necessary but I usually default to it instead of `->`. `KSetPartitions` generates 6 partitions of various lengths and the list is huge, but we are only interested in six pairs of two elements each that are selected by the `Cases` command.

Answer (score 0):

We can generalize the method in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/288159/125) to partitions with arbitrary length sub-lists.

First a function to generate replacement rules:

```
ClearAll[makeRule]

makeRule[m_Integer] := Module[
 {$symbols = Map[$s |-> Map[Symbol[$s <> ToString@#] &]@Range[m]]@{"$x", "$y"}},
   RuleDelayed @@ 
    {Prepend[Pattern[$a, Blank[List]]] @
       Apply[Riffle] @
       MapThread[Thread @ Pattern[#, #2[]] &] @
       {$symbols, {Blank, BlankNullSequence}}, 
     Apply[{Join[$a, {#}], ## & @@ #2} &] @ $symbols}];
```

***Examples:***

```
makeRule[2]
```

> ```
> {$a_List, $x1_, $y1___, $x2_, $y2___} :>   
>   {Join[$a, {{$x1, $x2}}],    $y1, $y2}
> ```

```
makeRule[3]
```

> ```
> {$a_List, $x1_, $y1___, $x2_, $y2___, $x3_, $y3___} :>   
>  {Join[$a,     {{$x1, $x2, $x3}}], $y1, $y2, $y3}
> ```

Use `makeRule` with `ReplaceList` + `Nest` to generate the desired list of partitions:

```
ClearAll[kPartitions]  

kPartitions[list_List, k_Integer] /; Divisible[Length @ list, k] := 
  Map[Splice] @ Nest[Catenate@*Map[ReplaceList[makeRule @ k]], 
     {Prepend[{}] @ list}, Length[list]/k]

kPartitions[n_Integer, k_Integer] /; Divisible[n, k] := kPartitions[Range[n], k]
```

***Examples:***

```
Length @ kPartitions[12, #] & /@ Rest[Most @ Divisors[12]]
```

> ```
> {10395, 15400, 5775, 462}
> ```

```
Length @ kPartitions[15, #] & /@ Rest[Most @ Divisors[15]]
```

> ```
> {1401400, 126126}
> ```

```
Length @ kPartitions[16, #] & /@ Rest[Most @ Divisors[16]]
```

> ```
> {2027025, 2627625, 6435}
> ```

```
Short[kPartitions[CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; 12]], 2], 10]
```

[image]

```
Short[kPartitions[CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; 12]], 3], 10]
```

[image]

```
Short[kPartitions[CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; 16]], 8], 10]
```

[image]

**Note/Warning:** For `{n, k}` pairs that generate a *large* number of partitions you will get a kernel crash.